# Quarto installed version in website page-footer

Tags: html, lua, yaml, knitr, quarto

In the `_quarto.yml` file of an RStudio website project, is there a way to get the installed quarto version into the page-footer without having to hard-code it?

```
website:
  page-footer:
    left: "Powered by [Quarto](https://quarto.org/) v1.3.24"
```

Comment: Have you tried left: !expr paste0(‘.. version ‘, quarto::quarto_version())

Comment: I can get that to work in a `.qmd` code chunk, e.g. following `#| fig-cap:`, but the website `page-footer` is in the `_quarto.yml` file and just renders an empty space there.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's a quick'n'dirty method using a Lua filter: Quarto reads processing instructions as raw HTML; we use that as a placeholder and replace it with the actual version in Lua:

```yaml
website:
  page-footer:
    left: "Powered by [Quarto](https://quarto.org/) <?quarto.version?>"

filters:
  - quarto-version.lua
```

where `quarto-version.lua` is a file in the main directory that contains this code:

```lua
function RawInline (raw)
  if raw.format:match 'html' and raw.text == '<?quarto.version?>'then
    return tostring(quarto.version)
  end
end
```

Comment: @Carl Your question motivated me to create [my first PR](https://github.com/quarto-dev/quarto-cli/pull/3618) for Quarto. Thanks for that :)

Comment: A worthy addition @tarleb :)

Comment: Hi, I'm getting this error: `Error running filter /Users/matthew/personal_website/quarto-version.lua:
/Users/matthew/personal_website/quarto-version.lua:1: unexpected symbol near '{'`. Do you know what could be causing this?

Comment: Never mind! I was making my .lua file in TextEdit on Mac and it turns out my text was not plain text. For those interested: create a .lua file by opening TextEdit, copy the code in, go to Format tab -> Make Plain Text, save, then rename the file with the .lua extension. Success! Thank you @tarleb!